# Save handler without a nested "deferred antipattern"

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise

I have an application in which a user makes a change, and when they click Save they will be prompted to confirm, and the appropriate REST call will be made if they agree. The intial call to `Save()` returns a promise that is fulfilled if the call returned successfully, or rejected if there was an error or the user canceled the confirmation.

I've boiled my actual implementation down to an equivalent example in order to highlight the (anti)pattern:

```
//assume confirm() and commit() are functions that return a promise:
//confirm() will be fulfilled or rejected based on a user choice
//commit() will be fulfilled or rejected based on the response from a RESTful web call

function save() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    confirm().then(function(response) {
        commit().then(function(response) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }).catch(function(rejection) {
            deferred.reject(rejection);
        });
    }, function(rejection) {
        deferred.reject(rejection);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

This stuck out to me rather clearly as the deferred antipattern, and so I refactored it to this:

```
function save() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    confirm().then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(commit());
    }, function(rejection) {
        deferred.reject(rejection);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Subsequently, it still looked like the deferred antipattern, and after a little while of thinking and Googling, I reduced it to this:

```
function save() {
    return confirm().then(function(response) {
        return commit();
    }, function(rejection) {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    });
};
```

Now, that looks pretty good to me, but I'm not sure if it's as good as it can be. All three versions above are functional, but is there perhaps a fourth iteration that would reduce it even further, or is this the simplest form for this depth of promises?

[I've created a fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/rsxjqc5o/1/) for anyone who may want to see it in action.

Comment: Just to chime in, a "deferred" is a read-write promise. Putting it the other way around, a promise is a read-only deferred. Essentially they are the same thing. Both have `then`, but only deferreds expose the `resolve` and `reject` method publicly. For promises, they're only accessible at the constructor. Deferreds are usually found in the place of operation, while promises are the ones you pass around for listening.

Comment: Neat idea. I've never thought about it like that, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could further simplify it to:

```
function save() {
    return confirm().then(commit, $q.reject);
};
```

Though you don't really gain anything.

Comment: Interesting. Would that propogate the rejection value, or swallow it and return an empty one?

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried it myself and it does seem to propogate the deepest response/rejection all the way out. Thanks for seeing that!

Comment: One downside I see to simplifying like this is that `commit` will be called with the resolved value of `confirm()` (assuming success.) So while this shortening is valid for an implementation where the analogue to `commit` takes no arguments, this cannot be used in a situation where the arguments to `commit` matter. This is, of course, outside of my original question, but I think it should be mentioned for anyone else who sees this option.

Comment: If your `commit` analogue required anything other than `response`, you are correct, this wouldn't work.

Comment: In my code, yes, that is the case. My question was directed towards the pattern of how to accomplish this in general, though, so this is still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You can also leave out reject. Your code would look like:

```
function save() {
    return confirm().then(function(response) {
        return commit();
    });
};
```

The promise returned by `then()` will automatically be rejected if the promise returned by `confirm()` is rejected.

Combining with @ShaunH's answer you would be left with

```
function save() {
    return confirm().then(commit);
};
```

Comment: Nice! The downside I commented on @ShaunH's answer applies to your second example as well, but that's not really material to the question. Thanks for pointing out that the rejection handler was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
function save() {
    return confirm().then(function(response) {
        return commit();
    }, function(rejection) {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    });
};
```

can be replaced with:

```
function save() {
    return confirm().then(function(response) {
        return commit();
    })
    ['catch'](function(error){
        <<error handling logic here>>
    });
};
```

This gives you the capability of handling all the errors in one `catch` block. The same `catch` block can be moved to the `save()` promise invoker too. Note that I intentionally used `['catch']` instead of `.catch()` because JSHint is known to cry over it.

If you don't care about the errors then [Planky's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39070/planky) answer is the most concise one you can use often.